# How can i save the selected option of this drop down menu into session without submit button php

Tags: php, session

I have gone through several related question without any luck. I want to save the option selected in the drop down menu into a $_SESSION[] without using the submit button as i have to carry the selected option into several pages before submitting the form. Any help without using java script

```
<form method="post" action="consel.php">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE startunix > '$nowtime' ORDER BY starttime LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage" ;
$retval = mysql_query($sql);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
      {
       echo "<div align='center'><span class='style3'>{$row['home']} VS ".
       "{$row['away']} </span></div>".
       "<font color='#000000' size='2'>{$row['country']} | {$row['league']} | Time:{$row['starttime']} </font> <br> ".
     "<select name='gm[$row[gamecode]|$row[starttime]|$row[home]|$row[away]]' >
     <option value=''>Select option</option>
                <option value='1'>YES</option>
                <option value='2'> NO</option>
                <option value='3'>Total Goals</option>
                <option value='4'>Total </option>
                <option value='5'>Goals</option>

         </select>".
     "<hr>";
                }
   ?>
  <input type="submit" name="play" value="Calculate" />
   </form>
```

Comment: you question is somehow ambigious, you don't want to use submit and also not interested in js, then I think you got to come up with a new web technology

Comment: it seems its possible with session but i really cant figure it out but if you have a suggested answer, its appreciated.

Comment: For me I would have use AJAX

Comment: ok. kindly post something about it.

Comment: really, okay do you know pure AJAX syntax

Comment: No. I have never used Ajax before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82433/discussion-between-gideon-appoh-and-scylla).

Comment: AJAX is Javascript .... xDDD LOL! Is impossible to do without any interaction. If you don't want a button or a javascript solution, I reffer you to first comment that you can research a new web technology

Comment: Its just best you make a constructive suggestion. been struck on this for a while now and its not getting lol.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is the ajax script to interact with your php file. Here I named mine yesno.php and also the response its just an empty div on my html page.

```
        <script>
        function session () {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open ('GET', 'yesno.php?value='+document.getElementById('id_of_select_field').value, true);
            xmlhttp.send ();
        }
    </script>
```

Then in your select option you just add an event handler to it like

```
<select id="id_of_select_field" onchange="session()">
    //options
</select>
```

From your codes there is no id attached to the select field so add one and change the id in the ajax (**id_of_select_field**) to that one.

So on your yesno.php you just grab the value with

```
$value = $_GET['value'];
```

and continue your codes.

Comment: error returns undefined variable value. gone through ajax tutorial on w3 and tizag too but cant get it to work. I tried saving the Options into session but it returns only the last value, selected or not.

Comment: on this line `$value = $_GET['value'];`

Comment: on the ajax link (i.e. on my answer session.php?value) what did you use in your work. Because undefined variable, value means there is not GET variable called value

Comment: I didn't change a thing in your script, except create session.php file and use `$value = $_GET['value'];` in my yesno.php file

Comment: did you use the $value on the session.php file or yesno.php file

Comment: i tied using it in session.php and later tried yesno.php but returns same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82564/discussion-between-gideon-appoh-and-scylla).